# Pandas DataFrame from dictionary with nested lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

```
my_dict = { 'company_a': [],
            'company_b': [ {'gender': 'Male',
                            'investor': True,
                            'name': 'xyz',
                            'title': 'Board Member'} ],
            'company_c': [],
            'company_m': [ {'gender': 'Male',
                            'investor': None,
                            'name': 'abc',
                            'title': 'Advisor'}, 
                            {'gender': 'Male',
                            'investor': None,
                            'name': 'opq',
                            'title': 'Advisor'} ],
            'company_x': [],
            'company_y': [] }
```

How do I convert the above Python dictionary to a Pandas dataframe with these columns: `company, gender, investor, name, title`

The column `company` will be populated by the top-level keys of `my_dict`. The other columns will be populated with the values in the dictionaries within the arrays.

I've tried `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')`, but it doesn't give me what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version fills all missing values with `None`:

```
data = {'company': [], 'gender': [], 'investor': [], 'name': [], 'title': []}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    for entry in v:
        data['company'].append(k)
    if not v:
        data['company'].append(k)
    for name in ['gender', 'investor', 'name', 'title']:
        has_entry = False
        for entry in v:
            has_entry = True
            data[name].append(entry.get(name))
        if not has_entry:
            data[name].append(None)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     company gender investor  name         title
0  company_a   None     None  None          None
1  company_y   None     None  None          None
2  company_b   Male     True   xyz  Board Member
3  company_c   None     None  None          None
4  company_x   None     None  None          None
5  company_m   Male     None   abc       Advisor
6  company_m   Male     None   opq       Advisor
```

You can also replace all `None` with `NaN`:

```
print(df.fillna(np.nan))
```

Output:

```
     company gender investor name         title
0  company_a    NaN      NaN  NaN           NaN
1  company_y    NaN      NaN  NaN           NaN
2  company_b   Male     True  xyz  Board Member
3  company_c    NaN      NaN  NaN           NaN
4  company_x    NaN      NaN  NaN           NaN
5  company_m   Male      NaN  abc       Advisor
6  company_m   Male      NaN  opq       Advisor
```

Comment: Nice solution, better as my deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy, but this is flexible depending on the attributes in your nested dictionaries, and will put the companies in their own column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['company'])
i = 0

for company in my_dict:
    for nested_dict in my_dict[company]:
        df.loc[i,'company'] = company
        for attribute in nested_dict.keys():
            df.loc[i, attribute] = nested_dict[attribute]
        i += 1
```

output:

```
Out[46]:
    company     name  gender  title         investor
0   company_m   abc   Male    Advisor       NaN
1   company_m   opq   Male    Advisor       NaN
2   company_b   xyz   Male    Board Member  True
```